# If the composition of two functions is differentiable, and one of them is differentiable, must the second one also be differentiable?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that we have three distinct functions $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, and that $f=g \circ h$, where $\circ$ denotes composition.

Does it necessarily follow that $h$ must be differentiable too?

Comment: What if $g$ is constant over the only interval where $h$ fails to be differentiable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a modification of the hint about Constant function , given earlier by user [MPW](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/113214/mpw) , though I will give Non-Constant Example.

Let $f(x)=g(h(x))$ where $g(x)=x^2$ & $h(x)$ is like this :

$h(x) = +x \text{ [ if x is rational ] }$
$h(x) = -x \text{ [ if x is irrational ] }$

In general , we can check that $h$ has no Derivative , while $g$ has Derivative $2x$
More-over , $f(x) \equiv (\pm x)^2 \equiv x^2$ , thus $f$ will have Derivative $2x$

This is a Counter-Example to the Claim.

HIGHLIGHT :
Even when $h$ is erratic/chaotic/weird , having no Derivative , "smooth" $g$ can "eliminate" that erraticness/chaos/weirdness to give "smooth" $f$.

Comment: We could tweak $h(x)$ Eg by involving $\pm x^3$ , with no change to $g(x)$ , to then get $f(x)$ involving $x^6$ : There are a lot of ways to tweak the Over-all Example to suit additional Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider $\;f(x):=|\cos x|\;$ at $\;x=0\;$ .

Comment: This is not a counterexample. Your $g$ is not differentiable.

Comment: I didn't even see the name of the functions. The above indeed is a counterexample for what the OP asked in the head of his question. I didn't think the order of the functions composing matters, but if it does then the OP can say it.

Comment: Forget about names, OP requires that the composition and the outer function in the composition be differentiable. Your outer function is the absolute value function, which is not differentable.

Comment: @MPW Nop, that is not what the header of his question says. Read again. Now I can see that in the body of his question he gave names to the functions and wrote that, and yet I'm still not sure whether he REALLY meant what you say or else what I wrote, answering the title of his post, is right. Maybe he will tell us... And anyway: you can leave your downvote. I really don't care.

Comment: I didn’t downvote. Did you read the question? It gives details not present in the title. It **specifically** says which two of the three functions are required to be differentiable, and asks about the third. There is no ambiguity, right? You shouldn’t be answering the title, but rather the question. The title is ambiguous but the question itself is not.

Comment: Exactly my point: the header is explicit (apparently) and according to it I solved. If the OP needs some order in the composition he can say so.

Comment: But the title can’t ever be considered alone. There generally isn’t enough room in the title to ask a question with all details. Otherwise, why would we bother to have a question body? *Always* read the question and answer that, not just the summary title which is necessarily incomplete.

Comment: I've no time to read all the questions in all the cases. The title seemed to be pretty clear and straightforward. The body of the question is used many times to develop the OP's own work, ideas and etc. Anyway, if the OP had something to say he could have said it. He apparently hadn't anything.

Comment: I will negate the downvote with my upvote , though I see that both View Points are valid here : (1) If OP thinks this is not what was asked , OP should respond (2) We should check Question Details to complete Picture on what OP wants since title is too short & will be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and help!
two quick things 1. order matters as per the body of the question. I get why someone wouldn't get it just form the title so no point fighting about it, but if someone is right, is the person who read the full text, obviously.

Comment: 2. let's not assume that everyone who asks questions on here/ does math is a man lol